# Trying to Automate/Loop a Save Function

Tags: php

EDIT: the difference between the pages are the simply $q1, $q2, $q3 becomes, for example, $q13, $q14, $q15 - they are questions in the form.

Hi all,

I have the following code:

```
$rguid = $_POST["r"];
$ip=substr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], 0, 50);
$browser=substr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 0, 255);   

$q1 = $_POST["q1"];
$q2 = $_POST["q2"];
$q3 = $_POST["q3"];
$q4 = $_POST["q4"];
$q5 = $_POST["q5"];
$q6 = $_POST["q6"];
$q7 = $_POST["q7"];
$q8 = $_POST["q8"];

$respondent_id = decode_respondent_guid($rguid);
$rcount=respondent_status($respondent_id);

if ($rcount==0) {

    $proc = mysqli_prepare($link, "INSERT INTO tresults (respondent_id, ip, browser, q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6, q7, q8) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($proc, "issiiiiiiii", $respondent_id, $ip, $browser, $q1, $q2, $q3, $q4, $q5, $q6, $q7, $q8);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($proc);
    $mysql_error = mysqli_error($link);
    if ($mysql_error!="") {
        printf("Unexpected database error: %s\n", $mysql_error);
        mysqli_stmt_close($proc);
        mysqli_clean_connection($link);
        exit();
    } else
    {
        mysqli_stmt_close($proc);
        mysqli_clean_connection($link);
        update_completion_status($respondent_id, 'Started');
        header("Location: page2.php?r=".$rguid);
    }
}
```

This code works a treat - no problem.

At the moment, that code appears on a 'save' page that relates to a 'form' page (i.e. if I have 5 .php pages with a form on each, I need 5 save.php pages to save each pages data to the database) to save data to my SQL database.  What I would like is to have a single save.php page that will work with as many 'form' pages as I have.  So instead of manually having to setup and change each save page, it automates it.

I've no idea of the coding to do this, though I suspect something like a foreach or loop etc.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,

Homer.

Comment: You forgot to mention one little thing. the difference between save pages

Comment: @ Col Shrap - provided the differences, essentially they are questions, so each save page has different $q's on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can essentially set the "action" of the form on each of your 5 form pages to the same "save" page.  But you have to be aware of what each save page is doing that might be different from the rest, and generalize.  For instance, at the end of your script you are redirecting to a particular page (page2.php).  If save #1 is supposed to go to a different page, you have to pass in to this script (from your form) enough information to determine where that redirect should go.

Comment: @Matt - thanks Matt - yep am aware that I can generalise and this is what I want to do - a single save page for all/any of the form pages.  I understand that things like the redirect will need to be a variable - got that covered - it's how to automate the other stuff I'm struggling with.

Answer (score 0):

With reference to the questions raised above and the ever-present caveat that my answer may not be perfect...

I would suggest creating a single "**save.php**" file to handle the storing of these answers into the database. To differentiate between the pages sending the answers to this file, simple include an additional POST field called "**page**" (or similar). That field can be contained within the form being submitted as a *hidden* field.

I would also suggest that adding two additional fields called "**firstQuestion**" and "**lastQuestion**" and containing the integers of the first and last questions from that page would then make the coding of the handler much easier.

Then, within the "**save.php**" file, you could have the following:

```
$fields = array();

$firstQ = int_val( $_POST['firstQuestion'] );
$lastQ = int_val( $_POST['lastQuestion'] );

for( $i=$firstQ ) ; $i<=$lastQ ; $i++ ) {
    $fields[$i] = mysqli_real_escape_string( $link , $_POST['q'.$i] );
}

$sqlFields = 'q'.implode( ', q' , array_keys( $fields ) );
$sqlValues = implode( ', ' . $fields );

$sqlQuery = sprintf( 'INSERT INTO tresults (respondent_id, ip, browser, %s ) VALUES ( %s, %s, %s, %s );' ,
              $sqlFields ,
              $respondent_id ,
              $ip ,
              $browser ,
              $sqlValues );
$proc = mysqli_prepare( $link, $sqlQuery );
mysqli_stmt_execute( $proc );
```

Then, further down, where you redirect to the next page, you can simply gather the `$_POST['page']` variable, add one, and insert that into the page name.

```
$redirectPage = 'page'.( int_val( $_POST['page'] )+1 ).'.php';
header( 'Location: '.$redirectPage.'?r='.$rguid );
```